# single page website opening in wrong section

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, singlepage

so I have created a single page website that uses a jQuery smooth scroll to navigate to sections of a website. For some reason, when ever I open the page in a browser (ive tested on multiple browsers and computers), the website opens up half way down the page instead of at the top of the page.

here is the script I am using to create the smooth scrolling.

here is the website

> http://usspcatalystcentre.org.uk/

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        function filterPath(string) {
            return string
            .replace(/^\//,'')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
            .replace(/\/$/,'');
        }

        var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
        var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

        // Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
        $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {

            // Ensure it's a same-page link
            var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
            if (  locationPath == thisPath
                && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
                && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {

                    // Ensure target exists
                    var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
                    if (target) {

                        // Find location of target
                        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                        $(this).click(function(event) {

                            // Prevent jump-down
                            event.preventDefault();

                            // Animate to target
                            $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 700, function() {

                                // Set hash in URL after animation successful
                                location.hash = target;

                            });
                        });
                    }
            }

        });

        // Use the first element that is "scrollable"  (cross-browser fix?)
        function scrollableElement(els) {
            for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
                var el = arguments[i],
                $scrollElement = $(el);
                if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
                    return el;
                } else {
                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                    var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                    if (isScrollable) {
                        return el;
                    }
                }
            }
            return [];
        }

    });
    </script>
```

thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Apply remove `autofocus` from your input elements.

> **[Autofocus](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_autofocus.asp)**:
>
> When present, it specifies that an  element should
>   automatically get focus when the page loads

The above means that when an input element has autofocus enabled, the page will be scrolled down to that element on page load, which was also the problem in your case.

A sample [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/4BqVW/) explaining the scenario.

Hope it helps